# Intermittent Display of Vine Embed in Bootstrap Modal, Chrome/iPad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, embed, vine

I've made Vine's embed successfully in Bootstrap (3) Modal popups.

However they intermittently display as blank (but with audio) on Chrome and iPad.. Particularly after a (F5) refresh/reload and screen resize (chrome), or clicking quickly through.

The embed is a standard Vine embed with audio & autoplay on. (though iPads ignore the autoplay).

When I get a blank Vine embed screen, F12 developer tools shows that within the Vine iframe body, there is:

```
<div class="embed embed-simple not-mobile" style="height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

If I adjust the dimensions in F12 (e.g. height: 0px; width: 0px;), it appears. I've tried adding a min-height & width to the parent div, this does not affect it.

Any ideas what to do next?!

See here: testkitten.com/cute-pets-quiz/ - or should I just not use Modals?

Comment: Is it possible to use an alternate vine embed file, that has forced height and width in it? https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js